# Use output of 'jq' on a curl command as a condition in a while loop

Tags: bash, curl

I want this statement to keep looping while the value of the json field in this api response is null.

```
while $(curl --location --request GET "https://example.com/integration-test/results/json"| jq '.result') == null
    do
    echo "Waiting for Integration tests to finish. Trying again in 10 seconds."
    sleep 2
done
```

The `== null` obviously doesn't work, but its illustrative of what I'm going for. When the Integration tests finish this api call will instead return SUCCESS or FAILURE in 'result'. Thats when I want the loop to stop.

Comment: What is the output of the `wget ... | jq ...` command that you want to test for? Is it actually going to be the string "null", or just *nothing*, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the `-e` argument to `jq` to make its exit status reflect its output (emitting a failed exit status when the only output is *either* `null` or `false`).

Writing the code below for clarity rather than terseness (using explicit grouping operators to make it clear that the negation applies to the entire pipeline):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o pipefail  # make a failure on the left-hand side fail the entire pipeline
while ! { curl --fail -L "https://example.com/integration-test/results/json" \
          | jq -e '.result' >/dev/null; }; do
    echo "Waiting for Integration tests to finish. Trying again in 10 seconds."
    sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the comparison in a conditional expression.

```
while [[ "$(curl --location --request GET "https://example.com/integration-test/results/json"| jq '.result')" == null ]]
do
    ...
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately my jq knowledge is very rudimentary. That would be a good alternate answer.